# Dice program with loop

Tags: python

I'm doing a program and the task is Write a program that simulates the toss of a pair of six sided dice (it would generate 2 to 12).

The code simulates the first throw of a dice game of “craps”.

The user loses if they throw a 2, 3 or 12 (Output the dice total and “You Lost”)
If the user throws a 7, they win (Output the dice total and “You Win”)
If they throw anything else, that value is their “point” (Output the dice total )
No input file, No output file, prompt the user to enter how many times they want to roll the dice. The rolls are separate and independent to each other.

A function called roll_dices will return two random numbers represents the roll of two dices.   random.randint(1,6) is Python library function that returns a random number between 1 and 6 inclusive.  Use the random function because the number rolled on a dice should be random.

A function called win_lost will determine whether the user win or lost. This function should return the indication of win or lost and the value of the dice rolls.

This is my code so far and there is no output.

```
  import random

  # Variables
  AGAIN = int(input("How many times do you want to roll the dice "))
  MIN = 1
  MAX = 6

  def main():
    
      roll_dice(AGAIN)
      win_lost(dices)

  def roll_dice(AGAIN):
      for dice in range(AGAIN):
          X = random.randint(MIN, MAX)
          Y = random.randint(MIN,MAX)
          dices = X + Y
      return dices

  def win_lost(dices):
      if dices == 2 or dices == 3 or dices == 12:
          print('You rolled ', dices, '. You lost.', sep ='')

      elif dice == 7:
          print('You rolled 7. You win')

      else:
          print('You earned', dices, 'points.')

  # Calling the main function
  main()
```

Comment: Aren't you getting an error from `win_lost(dices)`? You never assigned the `dices` variable.

Comment: Why does `roll_dice()` need a loop? You're only returning the last pair of rolls.

Comment: You need `dices = roll_dice(AGAIN)`

Comment: @Barma where should I put it ?

Comment: In `main()` in place of just `roll_dice(AGAIN)`

Answer (score 0):

```
elif dice == 7:
```

need to change to

```
elif dices == 7:
```

for the loop

```
def win_lost(dices):
          if dices == 2 or dices == 3 or dices == 12:
              print('You rolled ', dices, '. You lost.', sep ='')
    
          elif dices == 7:
              print('You rolled 7. You win')

          else:
              print('You earned', dices, 'points.')
          REPEAT = input("Do you want go again? (Y/N)")
          if REPEAt == Y:
              main()
          else:
              pass
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this part but I still have the error message

Answer (score 0):

Modest change to your code.

```
import random
 
def main(rolls):
  '''
     Input is the number of rolls
  '''
  # Variables for min, max dice values
  MIN = 1
  MAX = 6
  result = []
  for rolls in range(rolls):  
      # loop rolls times
      roll = roll_dice(MIN, MAX)
      win_lost(roll)

def roll_dice(MIN, MAX):
      ' Generate dice total '
      X = random.randint(MIN, MAX)
      Y = random.randint(MIN, MAX)
      return X + Y

def win_lost(dices):
  ' Message of win/lost/points based upon dices total '
  if dices == 2 or dices == 3 or dices == 12:
      print('You rolled ', dices, '. You lost.', sep ='')

  elif dices == 7:
      print('You rolled 7. You win')

  else:
      print('You earned', dices, 'points.')
        
# Get number of rolls
rolls = int(input("How many times do you want to roll the dice "))

# Calling the main function
main(rolls)
```

**Test**

```
How many times do you want to roll the dice 5
You rolled 7. You win
You earned 5 points.
You earned 5 points.
You earned 11 points.
You earned 10 points.
```